# "Vagrancy" as a substitute for "vagary" in the phrase "the vagaries of (fashion, market, etc.)"

Tags: word-usage

As far as your English variety goes, is it OK to substitute *vagrancy* for *vagary* in such a phrase as *the vagaries of (fashion, mind, etc.)*?

E.g.

> Its popularity waxed and waned with the *[vagaries of fashion](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=PpFw9SCmwI4C&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=%22vagaries%20of%20fashion%22&source=bl&ots=s9FyAzSuBt&sig=1PS9gfybln1npo0qgz8Ws11aUKw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=u_ILU6mALqOt0QW_iIDoBg&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22vagaries%20of%20fashion%22&f=false)*...
>
> She had no time -- or money -- to follow the silly *[vagrancies of fashion](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=VTuFkZzCzI4C&pg=PT175&lpg=PT175&dq=%22vagrancies%20of%20fashion%22&source=bl&ots=_tXqWgTW_W&sig=KvFRfwyFTfon6xqsRq-0qudzDDQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=xPQLU6qkEaiO0AWMhIHwAw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22vagrancies%20of%20fashion%22&f=false)*...
>
> ...in the Earth's magnetic fields or the *[vagrancies of the weather](http://www.cambridge.org/il/academic/subjects/engineering/thermal-fluids-engineering/introduction-turbulent-flow)*...
>
> ...but it was the *[vagrancies of the market](http://m.foxbusiness.com/quickPage.html?page=32811&content=67687967&pageNum=-1)*...
>
> Kenya is highly vulnerable to the *[vagrancies of unreliable rainfall](http://books.google.fr/books?id=mw_tAAAAMAAJ&q=%22the%20vagrancies%20of%22&dq=%22the%20vagrancies%20of%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=0ZcMU5i9Lcmu0QXKyYGgAw&redir_esc=y)*...
>
> ...they could reduce the *[vagrancies of English orthography](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Ki8mAQAAIAAJ&q=%22the%20vagrancies%20of%22&dq=%22the%20vagrancies%20of%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=EpkMU8iRKY7e7AbTu4C4CA&redir_esc=y)*...

Comment: No. This is just wrong, and not even cleverly sarcastic.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod On the contrary, it is long-established usage.

Comment: Long-established, perhaps, but neither current nor idiomatic. It sounds at best pretentious, and at worse jarring.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod If it's good enough for Eudora Welty it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although in ordinary speech and writing the word *vagrancy* never signifies anything but the deplorable (and usually illegal) condition of wandering about without discernible means of support, it has in fact been used in formal discourse since the 17th century of anything which can be said to “wander about” in either a literal or a figurative sense. [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio102murruoft#page/n33/mode/2up) gives some examples:

> **1642** [...] Curious men will judge it a vagrancy To start thus from my scope.
>   **1778** Of this vacillation and vagrancy of mind, I impute a great part to a fortuitous and unsettled life.
>   **1861** The workings of conscience helped to check the vagrancies of the heart.

Some more recent instances by pretty unimpeachable authors:

> **1959** Knowing, as I did, the dangerous vagrancies of my consciousness I was afraid of meeting people ... —*Vladimir Nabokov*
>   **1978** Whatever is significant and whatever is tragic in its story live as long as the place does, though they are unseen, and the new life will be built upon these things — regardless of commerce and the way of rivers and roads, and other vagrancies. —*Eudora Welty*
>   **1988** And, most shakingly, there is the capriciousness of one's passions, the weakness of one's constitution, and the vagrancies of one's thoughts: that nigrescent thing, the self. —*Clifford Geertz*

I don't find any strikingly authoritative instance of the vagrancies of *fashion*, but *the weather*, *genius*, *history*, *the unpredictable free market*, *local politics*, *time*, *memory*, *tide and leeway* and many other unstable entities are reported by Google Books to be given to vagrancies.

Answer (score 9):

You have it backwards, "vagrancies of fashion" is a malapropism of "vagaries of fashion".

"Vagaries" are unpredictable changes.

"Vagrancy" is the condition of being a homeless and jobless wanderer, and is not normally made plural.

The two words are cognate; deriving from a Latin word meaning "to wander".

"Vagrancies of fashion" might be used as an ironic way of commenting on fashion, but this would be an intentional breaking of the normal rules of English for effect.